# ASP.Net MVC личный кабинет при Windows авторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть проект Asp Net MVC с авторизацией windows. То есть будет работать только внутри локальной сети. Реализовано подключение к AD и вывод всех пользователей на таблицу в виде телефонного справочника. Так же в проекте есть определение кто авторизовался. И так вопрос, как можно реализовать личный кабинет для каждого пользователя. Например для хранения фотографий. Я знаю что в AD можно хранить фотографии в атрибутах. Но хотелось чтоб фотографий было больше чем 2 шт. или хранения дополнительной информации отсутствующей в AD. Как подружить все это дело с MS SQL (там же придется хранить доп. информацию?)
Метод получение данных из AD

```
public ActionResult GridViewPartial()
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> persons = GetPeople();
        return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", persons);
    }
    public static List<Person> GetPeople()
    {

        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        var path = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "RCSON.local", "OU=RCSON, DC=RCSON, DC=local");

        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(path);
        user.Enabled = true;


        user.Name = "*";
        //user.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "*";
        user.EmailAddress = "*";
        //user.Description = "";
        var search = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher();
        search.QueryFilter = user;
        var results = search.FindAll();
        foreach (UserPrincipal item in results)
        {
            var directoryEntry = item.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

            people.Add(new Person
            {
                DisplayName = item.Name,
                PhoneNumber = item.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                ExtensionPhoneNumber = item.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                Email = item.EmailAddress,
                Office = directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value as string,
                Department = directoryEntry.Properties["subdivision"].Value as string,
                Title = directoryEntry.Properties["title"].Value as string,
                DepartmentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(directoryEntry.Properties["departmentNumber"].Value),
                Subdivision = directoryEntry.Properties["department"].Value as string,
                Manager = directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value as string,
                Mobile = directoryEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value as string,
                EmployeeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(directoryEntry.Properties["employeeNumber"].Value),
                company = directoryEntry.Properties["company"].Value as string,
                BirthDay = Convert.ToDateTime(directoryEntry.Properties["postOfficeBox"].Value)
            });
        }
        return people;
    }
```

И метод создание частичного представления для личного кабинета не могу сообразить

```
 public PartialViewResult Details(string name)
    {
        Person person = GetPeople()
            .Find(x => x.DisplayName == name);
        return PartialView(person);
    }
```

Как передать в него сведения о текущем авторизованном пользователе?

Comment: На файловой системе хранить картинки, лучше выделить под это дело отдельный сервер. На SQL завести табличку с именами файлов, путями и владельцами (есть варианты хранить фото прямо в БД, но я не сторонник такого подхода). В AD лучше ничего не хранить, чтобы AD не треснуло.

Comment: Да, я согласен хранить все в AD очень рискованное дело. Но вот как привязать к конкретному пользователю, который авторизовался на портале, Дополнительные данные. Может есть какие идеи?

Comment: А у вашего пользователя нет никакого уникального идентификатора? Что то, что может однозначно указать на конкретного пользователя?

Comment: Думаю у каждого пользователя AD, можно получить уникальный идентификатор. Что то типа SSID или другой атрибут. Но даже если получу, то можно как то эту задачу решить?

Comment: если к кому то обращаетесь, указывайте его ник вот так @Азат , иначе мы не получим уведомление о сообщении.

Comment: Какую задачу? Не понимаю вопроса. Вы сделали приложение на базе `NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, вам kestrel/iis внутри HttpContext.User.Identity возвращает имя пользователя в формате domain\login - по-моему этой информации вполне достаточно, чтобы сохранить его в базе. А если слазить в HttpContext.User.Claims то там лежат и такие штуки как primarysid и primarygrougsid и куча других групп (у меня например штук 60 этих групп навешано на мой логин) - по идее primarysid это и есть то, что в AD прописано, если хочется SID сохранять, а не логин.

Comment: если у вас есть уникальный ид юзера, что вам мешает хранить картинки для этого юзера? Ну сделайте табличку `ид юзера, путь к картинке`

Comment: @tym32167, Уникальным идентификатором может и DisplayName выступать. Но я не понимаю как сделать обращение к БД. в случае, если, например: Пришел новый сотрудник, я завел учетную запись в AD и как правило в телефонной справочник он появится автоматически так как идет запрос. А в БД как выгрузить его?

Comment: @AK, Столько же групп навешано и ною учетку. Но если вы предлагаете хранить данные файлово, Можете подсказать как это сделать? Например В правом верхнем углу портала у меня есть приветствие пользователя. И по нажатию на свою учетку открывается частичное представление где будут данные конкретного пользователя который авторизовался. Но как дополнить эти данные.

Comment: Зачем его выгружать в бд? Человек заходит на ваш сайт, в свой личный кабинет, вы проверяете есть ли для него фотки в вашей табличке.

Comment: Непонятно, что именно "загружать в БД". Если пользователь вошёл в систему, то он может нажать кнопку "загрузить изображение", вы обрабатываете этот пост запрос, парсите Files сохраняете их (например локально), добавляете строку в базу User = HttpContext.User.Identity, FileName = сгенерированное имя. В базе не нужно хранить весь список AD, вы же сами сказали что у вас авторизация Win Auth

Comment: @tym32167, а можно чуточку подробнее. Видимо навыков у меня 0...

Comment: @AK, Все, дошло)) Спасибо!

Comment: @AK 
`public PartialViewResult Details(string name)
        {
            Person person = GetPeople()
                .Find(x => x.DisplayName == name);
            return PartialView(person);
        }
`
Создал такой метод для частичного представления личного кабинета. Но не могу передать в него имя текущего авторизованного пользователя...

Comment: @tym32167, может сможете помочь? Я внес свой код в посте